# Update/merge row data from the same table with common name

Tags: php, mysql

Need help on how to merge the rows with the same Column A

```
tbl as table name

UPDATE a.ColumnA
FROM tbl a
INNER JOIN tbl b ON a.ColumnA = b.ColumnA
WHERE a.tbl = b.tbl
```

before

| ColumnID | ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  | data1 |
| 2 | 1 | data2 |  |
| 3 | 2 |  | data3 |
| 4 | 2 | data4 |  |

after

| ColumnID | Column A | Column B | Column c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| n | 1 | data2 | data1 |
| n | 2 | data4 | data3 |

Comment: It's probably easier to create a new table. It means you don't have to selectively delete certain records in the old table. You could use [INSERT INTO SELECT](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-into-select/). Note that, whatever you do, values in `ColumnID` will be lost.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the responds. Is it possible to show the INSERT INTO SELECT method? Does it goes with the CREATE tbl then INSERT INTO SELECT?

Comment: Yes, you first have to create new table, and then you can copy from the old table. Sorry, your question was closed, making it harder to answer it. Just look at the supposedly duplicate answers, they form the SELECT bit of the INSERT INTO SELECT query.